# How to address a PHP non-static class method in documentation?

Tags: php, oop

```
class A 
{
    public function f();
    public static function s();
}
```

It seems quite ok to name static method as **A::s()**, so as it called.
But what in case of non-static method?

Comment: please refer http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: same as static function A::f();

Comment: From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) — _:: is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class_. How should one read this: **1)** (overridden properties) or methods **2)** overridden(properties or methods)?